# unable to start activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexception list view not refreshing

Tags: android

I have a list activity that contains a list of all the prescriptions. When click on list item activity edit prescription is called which updates the table and on success switches back to the list activity and should reload it.

But after updating when i am going back to the list activity error:  unable to start activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexception is shown.

Line no. 87 in the stack trace is  pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID"); in the DocPresc List Activity.

Here is my list activity :

```
public class DocPresc extends ListActivity {

    //public static Context ctx;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        String pid;
        JSONArray products = null;
        EditText ailm,date,comment;
        Button delete;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single product url
        private static final String url_patient_presc = "http://192.168.44.208/get_prescription.php";


        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
      //  private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";
        private static final String TAG_AIL = "ailment";
        private static final String TAG_MED = "medicine_name";
        private static final String TAG_D1 = "qty1";
        private static final String TAG_D2 = "qty2";
        private static final String TAG_D3 = "qty3";
        private static final String TAG_DATE = "prescription_date";
        private static final String TAG_COM = "comment";
        private static final String TAG_DID = "dosage_id";

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.docpresc);
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
              .penaltyLog().build());

            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            Intent i = getIntent();

             Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
             pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID");
             System.out.println("Docpresc"+pid);

             ailm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
             date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date1);
             comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment1);
             new LoadPrescriptions().execute();






        }





        class LoadPrescriptions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {

                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("patient_id",pid));//search1.getText().toString()));
                 System.out.println("database"+pid);
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_patient_presc, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Patients: ", json.toString());


                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        //-----------------------------------
                        /*JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(0);

                        ailm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ailment1);
                        ailm.setText(product.getString(TAG_AIL));*/
                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable

                            String medicine = c.getString(TAG_MED).toUpperCase();
                            String qty1 = c.getString(TAG_D1).toUpperCase();
                            String qty2 = c.getString(TAG_D2).toUpperCase();
                            String qty3 = c.getString(TAG_D3).toUpperCase();
                            String dsg_id = c.getString(TAG_DID).toUpperCase();
                            //String ail = c.getString(TAG_AIL).toUpperCase();

                            ailm.setText(c.getString(TAG_AIL));
                            date.setText(c.getString(TAG_DATE));
                            comment.setText(c.getString(TAG_COM));


                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value


                            map.put(TAG_MED, medicine);
                            map.put(TAG_D1,qty1);
                            map.put(TAG_D2,qty2);
                            map.put(TAG_D3,qty3);
                            map.put(TAG_DID,dsg_id);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);  

                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                       }
                       });
                return null;
            }


            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                //  pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                DocPresc.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item2, new String[] {
                                    TAG_MED,TAG_D1,TAG_D2,TAG_D3,TAG_DID},
                                    new int[] {R.id.med,R.id.d1,R.id.d2,R.id.d3,R.id.did });
                        // updating listview
                        //setListAdapter(adapter);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                 });

            }

        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        //menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
        //menuSearch.setVisible(false);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }






        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

               // handle item selection

               switch (item.getItemId()) {

                  case R.id.add:

                      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",pid );
                    System.out.println("bundle"+pid);
                    Intent i = new Intent(DocPresc.this,AddPresc.class);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
                    //finish();


                     // startActivity(new Intent(DocPresc.this,AddPresc.class));
                     // finish();
                    //  Intent i = getIntent();
                     // finish();
                    //  startActivity(i);
                 // case R.id.print:




                     return true;

                  default:

                     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

              }

            }

        public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //onAttach(getActivity());
            //lv.setAdapter(adapter);


            String did1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.did)).getText().toString();
            String med1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.med)).getText().toString();
            String dg1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d1)).getText().toString();
            String dg2 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d2)).getText().toString();
            String dg3 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.d3)).getText().toString();

        //  System.out.println("all  patient"+id1);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID",did1 );
            bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID1",med1 );
            bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID2",dg1 );
            bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID3",dg2 );
            bundle.putString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID4",dg3 );


            //  System.out.println("bundle"+id1);
            Intent i = new Intent(DocPresc.this,EditPresc.class);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(i,100);




            //passData(date);


        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // if result code 100
            if (resultCode == 100) {
                // if result code 100 is received
                // means user edited/deleted product
                // reload this screen again
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }



}
```

And here is the Edit prescription activity

```
public class EditPresc extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    //public static Context ctx;

        EditText medicine;
        EditText dosage1;
        EditText dosage2;
        EditText dosage3;
        Button edit;
        ImageButton up1 , up2,up3;
        ImageButton down1,down2,down3;
        String did,medi,q1,q2,q3;
        int count = 1;
        //JSONArray products = null;




        //int pid = "100";


        //private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single product url
      //  private static final String url_getdosage = "http://192.168.44.208/get_dosage.php";
        private static final String url_updatedosage = "http://192.168.44.208/update_dosage.php";


        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
      //  private static final String TAG_PATIENT_ID = "patient_id";

        private static final String TAG_MED = "medicine_name";
        private static final String TAG_D1 = "qty1";
        private static final String TAG_D2 = "qty2";
        private static final String TAG_D3 = "qty3";


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.editpresc);
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
              .penaltyLog().build());

            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            Intent i = getIntent();

             Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
             did  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID");
             medi  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID1");
             q1  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID2");
             q2  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID3");
             q3  = extras.getString("TAG_DOSAGE_ID4");

             medicine = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.atxt1);
             dosage1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
             dosage2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
             dosage3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text3);

             medicine.setText(medi);
             dosage1.setText(q1);
             dosage2.setText(q2);
             dosage3.setText(q3);






             System.out.println("Editpresc"+did);

            //send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
            up1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up1);
         down1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down1);
         dosage1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        up2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up2);
         down2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down2);
         dosage2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text2);
        up3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.up3);
         down3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.down3);
         dosage3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text3);
         //dosage1.setText("1");
         up1.setOnClickListener(this);
         up2.setOnClickListener(this);
        up3.setOnClickListener(this);
        down1.setOnClickListener(this);
        down2.setOnClickListener(this);
        down3.setOnClickListener(this);
        //ailment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.atxt);

        //comment = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ctxt);
        //presc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.presc_id);
        edit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

       //   new GetDosage().execute();



        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 new EditDosageDetails().execute();

            }
        });




        }

    private class EditDosageDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //  JSONObject product;

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            //JSONObject product = null;
            //id.setText(100);
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {


                   String med = medicine.getText().toString();
                   System.out.println("editdosage"+med);
                   String do1 = dosage1.getText().toString();
                   String do2 = dosage2.getText().toString();
                   String do3 = dosage3.getText().toString();
                   // Building Parameters
                   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medicine_name", med));

                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dosage_id", did));
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty1", do1));
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty2", do2));
                   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty3", do3));

                       JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_updatedosage,
                               "POST", params);
                        // json success tag
                      // Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                       // check for success tag
                       try {
                           int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                           if (success == 1) {
                               // successfully created product
                               Intent i = getIntent();
                               setResult(100, i);
                               finish();
                               // super.onBackPressed();
                               // closing this screen

                           } else {
                               // failed to create product
                           }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
         //      }
               }

            });
                    //return product;
             return null;

          //  });

           // return product;
        }

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        //menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
        //menuSearch.setVisible(false);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.up1:
                int a=Integer.parseInt(dosage1.getText().toString());
                int b = a+1;
                dosage1.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
                break;

            case R.id.down1:
                 a=Integer.parseInt(dosage1.getText().toString());
                 b = a-1;
                dosage1.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
                break;

            case R.id.up2:
                 a=Integer.parseInt(dosage2.getText().toString());
                 b = a+1;
                dosage2.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
                break;

            case R.id.down2:
                a=Integer.parseInt(dosage2.getText().toString());
                 b = a-1;
               dosage2.setText(new Integer(b).toString());

            case R.id.up3:
                a=Integer.parseInt(dosage3.getText().toString());
                 b = a+1;
               dosage3.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
               break;

            case R.id.down3:
                a=Integer.parseInt(dosage3.getText().toString());
                 b = a-1;
               dosage3.setText(new Integer(b).toString());
               break;
            //case R.id.save:
            //  System.out.println("save pressed");



            }


        }



}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbar/com.example.actionbar.DocPresc}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at com.example.actionbar.DocPresc.onCreate(DocPresc.java:87)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
06-13 17:59:35.558: E/AndroidRuntime(26369):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: check if extras/getExtras is null before trying to access data that may not exist?

Comment: In onActivityResult you probably need to create new Intent, because Intent is maybe context-dependent? Anyway I dont like your solution to finish and start new activity. You should call your asyncTask to load new data instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
pid  = extras.getString("TAG_PATIENT_ID");
You wrote this one the onCreate but there is a probleme There is not Extra if no item was selected here :

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
           // handle item selection

           switch (item.getItemId()) {

              case R.id.add:

                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",pid );
                System.out.println("bundle"+pid);
                Intent i = new Intent(DocPresc.this,AddPresc.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
                //finish();
```

Am not sure of my answer or if say bullshits but i can't see how your extra can be get in onCreate before an other activity put an extra and call this one

Comment: There is another activity which is putting the extra into this activity        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("TAG_PATIENT_ID",id1 );
  System.out.println("bundle"+id1);
  Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),DocPresc.class);
  i.putExtras(bundle);
  startActivity(i);

Comment: the flow is like list activity->list activity->activity